# Order of Apache Pig Transformations

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am reading through Pig Programming by Alan Gates.

Consider the code:

```
ratings = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/u.data' AS 
    (userID:int, movieID:int, rating:int, ratingTime:int);

metadata = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/u.item' USING PigStorage ('|') AS 
    (movieID:int, movieTitle:chararray, releaseDate:chararray, imdbLink: chararray);

nameLookup = FOREACH metadata GENERATE 
    movieID, movieTitle, ToDate(releaseDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy') AS releaseYear;

nameLookupYear = FOREACH nameLookup GENERATE 
    movieID, movieTitle, GetYear(releaseYear) AS finalYear;

filterMovies = FILTER nameLookupYear BY finalYear < 1982;

groupedMovies = GROUP filterMovies BY finalYear;

orderedMovies = FOREACH groupedMovies {
    sortOrder = ORDER metadata by finalYear DESC;
    GENERATE GROUP, finalYear;
    };

DUMP orderedMovies;
```

It states that

> "Sorting by maps, tuples or bags produces error".

I want to know how I can sort the grouped results.

Do the transformations need to follow a certain sequence for them to work?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the grouped results by year or are you trying to sort the movies within each group (year)?

Comment: @savagedata Trying to sort group results by year 1982, 1981, 1980 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to sort the grouped results, you do not need a nested foreach. You would use the nested foreach if you were trying to, for example, sort each movie within the year by title or release date. Try ordering as usual (refer to `finalYear` as `group` since you grouped by `finalYear` in the previous line):

```
orderedMovies = ORDER groupedMovies BY group ASC;

DUMP orderedMovies;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to sort the grouped values then you will have to use nested foreach. This will sort the years in descending order within a group.

```
orderedMovies = FOREACH groupedMovies {
      sortOrder = ORDER metadata by GetYear(ToDate(releaseDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')) DESC;
      GENERATE GROUP, movieID, movieTitle;
};
```

Comment: I have updated the code. The data is loaded to the 'metadata' table. The calculated date is in the 'nameLookup' table.

Comment: Receive Error 1200 -Expression is not a project expression on Line 16: sortOrder...

Comment: Still not working. releaseDate in metadata is chararray. If I understand correctly you want to order by chararray?

Comment: @HubCap Try GetYear(ToDate(releaseDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'))

Comment: Gives the error: Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'GetYear'

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The idea was to sort the group - see other answer.